# Can Camera Permission be requested from from Native Code(C/C++)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am trying to write an Android Native program using NDK that will access camera from the native code. But to access the camera I need permission even for native code. I found a sample provided by google to access camera from the native code but it checks the permission by calling a Java method written in the activity [[ref]](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/camera). Is there any way to check for the permission form the native code only, without extending the `NativeActivity`[[ref]](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na#jd-content)? Possibly not even accessing the Dalvik VM at all (which I believe will give me a better performance)

Comment: It may be possible (if there is a permission class written in c/c++) other wise no, the Java overhead should not be huge, try it stage by stage, leaping ahead will probably save you no time in the end. "delvicVM", it's [ART](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik) now, still binary compatible.

Comment: I know Dalvik has been replaced by ART. I also understand the overhead shouldn't be that much but yet that slight improvement will matter for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to check whether the permission was granted: try to open the camera device, and it will fail, or succeed.

To request the permission, you must use framework API explicitly. There is no C API for [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) or her alternatives (that's to answer *“Possibly not even accessing the Dalvik VM”*).

Note that you can avoid permissions request: you can instruct your user to grant the permission in System Settings for your App (no, I am not endorsing this approach, but if you have some special reason to *not* extend NativeActivity and have no Java code in your APK, you still can.

Comment: Ok that is a good solution, I'll check this out. What do you mean by Framework API? Are you talking about this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master?

Comment: By framework API, I mean that there is no C API for [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) or her alternatives (that's to answer *“Possibly not even accessing the Dalvik VM”*).